# Error #1009- Only when there is code present in main class

Tags: actionscript-3

Please do forgive me if this is a stupid question, by I really need to know the solution. So here I have a program that generates particles every set distance of space. My program consists of a document class, called supportForce and an object class(of the particle) called TheDot.
In the TheDot object class, I have the following code-

```
    package 
    {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        public class TheDot extends MovieClip
        {
            var base:Object = MovieClip(root);
            public function TheDot()
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            }
            private function eFrame(event:Event):void
            {
                if (base.currentFrame == 1){
                    trace ("G");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This code works perfectly (outputs G) until I add the following code into the document class, suportForce, under an ENTER_FRAME event-

```
var ctX:int = 0,ctY:int = 0,done:Boolean = false; 
while (done == false)
            {
                var dots:TheDot = new TheDot  ;
                dots.alpha = 0;
                dots.x +=  (25 * ctX);
                dots.y +=  (25 * ctY);
                ctX++;
                if (ctX == 22 && ctY == 20)
                {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (ctX == 22)
                {
                    ctX = 0;
                    ctY++;
                }
                stage.addChild(dots);
            }
```

So now, there is an Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at TheDot/eFrame(). I have declared all the variables in the correct place, and also the functions. Thanks in advance. I have the link to the .fla and .as files in my drive here, do use it if necessary.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8QnUfRAn9lKLUVqRjNSRHNpRkU&usp=sharing

Comment: You realise `enterFrame` is something done when the SWF refreshes its display buffer? If you have set SWF at 30fps then really you're just telling Flash to do 150 while-loops every 5 secs (ie: you want this app to crash your computer soon, isn't it?). Just leave enterframe alone excpet for animated code. Just make a new normal `function addDots () : void` and add your dots with a for-loop (not while-loop). Your `ctY++` seems like it should be outside of the **else** statement. Use nested For-loops (for X and Y). That's how its done in C-like language not with While loops.

Comment: You were **already** **[told to use nested for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35547100/2057709)**, just ignoring working advice? That middle code with two `for` loops is what you must do in a normal function (non-enterframe event). What is Base Object supposed to be and why push type `: Object` into a type `: MovieClip`.

Comment: @VC.One I am really sorry for troubling you. It's just that I am relatively new to this, which is why I have not quite understood everything yet. I really appreciate you looking into my other question, and assisting me with this one too. I have now put it under a nested loop. I just figured out that I could use `var base:Object = MovieClip(root);` then use the Base object to refer to the main file. I wanted to do this because I wanted to test collision with an instance of a symbol on the stage. Sorry again and thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST 
var dots:TheDot = new TheDot(**stage**);

```
public class TheDot extends MovieClip
{
    var base:Object;
    public function TheDot(stageRef:Stage)
    {
        base = stageRef;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    public function init(e:Event) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
    }

    private function eFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        if (base.currentFrame == 1){
            trace ("G");
        }            
    }
```

Try this!